# How to fix the error TeamsController#load_users is missing a template for this request format and variant

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a rails application.in a use case where I have to pop up a modal.problem is that modal is not popping up. if I make the partial file as normal then modal appears as a normal page which I don't want. since a week I am trying this little good news is at least it is showing the modal if I do _load_users.html.erb as load_users.html.erb but I want the partial file to be popped up as the modal.

I have used a link which triggers Ajax

// teams_controller

```
def load_users
  @user = User.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

//index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'link', load_users_teams_path, remote: true  %>

<div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

//_load_users.html.erb

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
  <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  **here comes whatever you want to show!**
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

//load_users.js.erb

```
$("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript( render 'load_users' ) %>");
$("#modal-window").modal()
```

It should show a pop-up modal on click of the link.

Comment: Try adding `format: :js` as an option to your load_users_teams_path call, this should make rails look for a js.erb file to load. You may also need to change it to `render partial: 'load_users'` in the js.erb file, not sure...

Comment: i did as you said but i am getting following error............... Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.

Comment: Not sure what would be causing that. Maybe remove the escape_javascript call and just leave the render in there? That's the only idea I've got, otherwise I'd tell you to look up that error

Comment: Actually, you know what that might be is changing the HTML on a pre existing DOM node. You might try something like append instead, it could help

Answer (score 0):

With your original setup was there nothing happening in the DOM or errors in browser console?

```
<div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any change to this as viewed in developer tools inspector when you click your remote link?

Might just be that when you replace the content of the #model-window that it still has the .hide class (I'm guessing this is display: none; or similar).

Comment: load_users Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable) this is my browser log

Comment: What controller/action/format is attempted as show in the rails log?